# can't acces to K8s ingress server

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I can't access the server deployed by ingress Kubernetes.

My project is structured like this:
I have a delpoy.sh that builds and pushes the images to dockerhub. There are two images "info" and "image". In order to link these images to Kubernetes, I have a yaml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: info-v1-deployment
  labels:
    app: info-v1
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: info-v1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: info-v1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: info-v1
          image: cloudcomputing2021/info:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          env:
            - name: FLASK_RUN_HOST
              value: 0.0.0.0
            - name: FLASK_RUN_PORT
              value: "1080"
            - name: FLASK_APP
              value: server.py
            - name: DB_HOST
              value: db_ip 
            - name: DB_PORT
              value: "3306"
            - name: DB_DBNAME
              value: watches
            - name: DB_USER
              value: user
            - name: DB_PASS
              value: password
            - name: HTTP_USER
              value: cloud
            - name: HTTP_PASS
              value: computing
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: image-v1-deployment
  labels:
    app: image-v1
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: image-v1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: image-v1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: image-v1
          image: cloudcomputing2021/image:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          env:
            - name: FLASK_RUN_HOST
              value: 0.0.0.0
            - name: FLASK_RUN_PORT
              value: "1080"
            - name: FLASK_APP
              value: server.py
            - name: HTTP_PASS
              value: computing
            - name: HTTP_USER
              value: cloud
      
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: info-v1-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: info-v1
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 1080
      nodePort: 30036

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: image-v1-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: image-v1
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 1080
      nodePort: 30037
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: cloud-computing-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /info/v1/*
            backend:
              serviceName: info-v1-service
              servicePort: 80
          - path: /image/v1/*
            backend:
              serviceName: image-v1-service
              servicePort: 80
---
```

this file creates an ingress and two services (one for image and one for info). This process runs smoothly. However, when I try to access the server via the cluster URL, I get a 502 error with the following message:

"Error: Server Error
The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds."

It is important to specify that the images work perfectly locally with docker-compose up so I deduce that the problem does not come from the images.

The Ingress state is: "Some backend services are in UNKNOWN state"

Comment: Welcome to the comminty @IOrakle
Please run following to get some information about your ingress:
`kubectl describe ingress cloud-computing-ingress`. Are you using k8s as a service or do you have your own cluster?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things:

1. You are exposing service with nodeport, in which case you can hit http://<any worker ip/hostname>:30037/ to access your application.
2. Can you check your ingress definition? please refer [ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)

Also, it might be helpful to check events for both pods/containers.